# Can't get my SUM() to appear correctly with 3 group conditions

Tags: mysql

So my data looks like this:

(The customer can make purchases multiple times a day so there can be multiple rows on the same day)

```
+------+----------+------+-----+
|      |          |      |     |
+------+----------+------+-----+
| date | customer | item | qty |
| 1/1  | A        | a    | 2   |
| 1/1  | A        | a    | 3   |
| 1/1  | A        | b    | 1   |
| 1/1  | B        | a    | 1   |
| 1/1  | C        | b    | 1   |
| 2/1  | A        | b    | 1   |
| 2/1  | B        | b    | 2   |
| 2/1  | B        | a    | 1   |
| 2/1  | A        | b    | 3   |
| 3/1  | B        | b    | 2   |
| 3/1  | C        | a    | 3   |
| 3/1  | B        | b    | 3   |
| 3/1  | A        | a    | 2   |
+------+----------+------+-----+
```

I need to have a daily total table something like this:

```
+----------+----------+------+-------+
|     date | customer | item | total |
+----------+----------+------+-------+
|     1/1  | A        | a    |     5 |
|     1/1  | A        | b    |     1 |
|     1/1  | B        | a    |     1 |
|     1/1  | C        | b    |     1 |
|     2/1  | A        | b    |     4 |
|     2/1  | B        | b    |     2 |
|     2/1  | B        | a    |     1 |
|     3/1  | B        | b    |     5 |
|     3/1  | C        | a    |     3 |
|     3/1  | A        | a    |     2 |
+----------+----------+------+-------+
```

The goal is to have a table which I can see the total qty of each item bought in a day by each company, and this table needs to be filtered by date/customer/item in other reports for later use.

Have tried

```
SELECT

date,
customer,
item,
SUM(qty) as total

FROM
data
group by 1,2,3
```

Have tried different variations for the the group condition like 1,2 or 1,3 or 2,3 but some the SUM(qty) number always seems to come out wrong :(

Comment: What does the query you tried output?

Comment: please see Strawberry's link and set up a fiddle showing what you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use column name instead of the column order

```
SELECT
  date,
  customer,
  item,
  SUM(qty) as total
FROM data
GROUP BY date, customer, item;
```

Comment: why use column name instead of order?

Comment: because it more clear for any one who look the query

Answer (score 0):

What Fahmi said - GROUP BY doesn't use column numbers, so you're grouping by the equivalent of
group by 'A','A','A'

The column number syntax only works with ORDER BY...

Comment: If there's some version of mysql where column number doesn't work, I don't know about it.  It should work just fine.